# How to use a different compare/merge tools for SLN files on Visual Studio using Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, merge, compare, solution

Comparing (and merging) two different version of Visual Studio Solution file can't be trivial...

In the past I successfully used [Tools for SLN file](http://slntools.codeplex.com), integrated into VS2015 with one-shot configuration (see [here](http://slntools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SLNTools%20Merge&referringTitle=Home)).

I was using TFS (Team Foundation Server) but 2 months ago I started with Git.

I can't configure "Tools for SLN file" because the "Tools\Options\Source Control" settings for Git plugin doesn't contain the "Configure User Tools" section.

The **global Git settings** doesn't have this section.

My question is:

*does exist the way to use a different compare/merge tools (for only some specific file extensions) when you are working with "Git plugin" on Visual Studio 2015?*

Comment: I'm also interested by this if you found anything